# Use Powershell to Activate Windows 2008 R2 Server

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

How do I use powershell to enter a key and then activate a Windows 2008 R2 installation?

Answer (score 2):

I've used `slmgr` utility - as described here:

- [Slmgr.vbs Options](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff793433.aspx)
- Example using cscript.exe /B to suppresses prompts:

`cscript.exe /B "c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs" -ipk XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX -ato`

And here:

- [Activation Issue seen with Windows 8 Enterprise from TechNet](http://blogs.technet.com/b/blainbar/archive/2012/08/21/activation-issue-seen-with-windows-8-enterprise-from-technet.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [How to Activate Windows 7 Through PowerShell](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/activate-windows-7-through-powershell-28450.html)

- Step 3: `$service= get-wmiObject -query "select * from SoftwareLicensingService" -computername` computer Replace "computer" with the computer name.
- Step 4: Install the license key. The following code adds the Windows activation license to the computer: `$service.InstallProductKey($key)` and `$service.RefreshLicenseStatus()`. Replace `$key` with your license key for Windows.

Comment: @KyleBrandt: unfortunately, I have no means to test it, but did you do `RefreshLicenseStatus`? Also, did you try restarting the machine after these steps?

Answer (score 1):

I've had this same exact problem on 2008 R2. Here's what I did.

```
$all_services = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT * FROM SoftwareLicensingService"
$all_services.InstallLicense($key)
$service = Get-WmiObject SoftwareLicensingProduct | Where-Object {$_.PartialProductKey}
$service.Activate()
$all_services.RefreshLicenseStatus()
```

Now, I'm not sure why $service doesn't have an install method. There's probably a more efficient way to do this, but the key point is you need to invoke the activate method before refreshing.